# If is working, equivalent Iif does not

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I cannot understand why this is working:

```
Function ToNumber(ByVal sVal As String) As Double
sVal = Replace(sVal, ",", ".")
If IsNumeric(sVal) Then
    ToNumber = CDbl(sVal)
Else
    ToNumber = 0
End If
End Function
```

while this one does not (I am getting a type mismatch):

```
Function ToNumber(ByVal sVal As String) As Double
sVal = Replace(sVal, ",", ".")
ToNumber = IIf(IsNumeric(sVal), CDbl(sVal), 0)
End Function
```

formally they should be equivalent. thank you.

Comment: `formally they should be equivalent` - no, in statement `IIF(cond,if_true,if_false)` both parts `if_true` and `if_false` evaluates regardless whether `cond` is `true` of `false`. So, even if `IsNumeric(sVal)` returns `False`, vba still evaluates `CDbl(sVal)`, but returns `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately VBA will evaluate **both** arguments in the `Iif`. In your case `CDbl(sVal)` gives you a type mismatch since it will be evaluated even if `IsNumeric(sVal)` is `False`.

Your best bet is to retain the `If`, `Else`, `End If` construct. Or, you could do this (retaining the comments since the code is complex):

```
Function ToNumber(ByVal sVal As String) As Double
    'note that (1) the error handling is reset to that in the caller
    '              when the function exits.
    '          (2) ToNumber is zero by default
    On Error Resume Next 
    ToNumber = CDbl(Replace(sVal, ",", "."))
End Function
```

(This is unlike the ternary in Java, C and C++ where exactly one of the expressions are evaluated).

Comment: I already tried that, but thanks for pointing out the default issue. to get a full picture of the solutions I also thought of `If Not IsNumeric(sVal) Then sVal = "0" End If / ToNumber = CDbl(sVal)`

Answer (score 0):

In the statement `IIf(IsNumeric(sVal), CDbl(sVal), 0)`, `CDbl(sVal)` is evaluated regardless of the result of IsNumeric and causes type mismatch the run time error.